# Unable to add Drawable to an ArrayList of Drawables - Type mismatch

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm building an ArrayList of drawables for a RecyclerView like this -

`private val draw: ArrayList<Drawable> = ArrayList()`

`draw.add(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(resources, R.drawable.one, null))`

But for the second line I get a Type Mismatch error -

`Required: Drawable`
`Found: Drawable?`

The import is `import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable`

I'm unable to figure out what is going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
draw.add(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(resources, R.drawable.one, null)!!)
```

instead of

```
draw.add(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(resources, R.drawable.one, null))
```

Comment: This worked. What is `!!` for?

Comment: it states that value is not nullable. Don't forget to accept and upvote the answer

Comment: the !! operator should be avoided. Otherwise you won't be taking advantage of the null safety feature of kotlin.

Comment: @Donki you're absolutely correct !!

Answer (score 1):

`ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(resources, R.drawable.one, null)` can return `Drawable?` -> which means this can also be null. Now your `ArrayList<Drawable>` does not allow nulls, so what you can do is to check if the drawable is not null and then add it to the list for example:

```
val drawable = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(resources, R.drawable.one, null)
drawable?.let { draw.add(it) }
```

Using `!!` throws NPE if value is null, so you will have to catch it and `?.` operator safely checks if the value is not null. Like a shorter `if (drawable != null)` condition

There is also third option where you can provide default drawable if null is found, using elvis operator.

```
val drawable = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(resources, R.drawable.one, null)
val defaultDrawable = ...
draw.add(drawable ?: defaultDrawable)
```